# Opera doesn't recognize 0.0.0.0 as localhost. Is this behaviour standard-conform?

Tags: firefox, opera, ip-address, localhost

Opera (version 10.10) under Linux (don't know about other OSes) does not recognize `http://0.0.0.0/` as local address (`http://127.0.0.1/`) , while Firefox does.

What is the difference between these addresses?

Which ob the two browsers in this case is standard conform?

**EDIT**
Not only `Firefox`, but also `Konqueror` and `wget` handle `0.0.0.0` same way as local address. So, could it be Linux-specific?

Comment: Should be on server fault I guess

Comment: It might very well be linux specific, or distribution-specific, or whatever. No windows application/tool i know of acts this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The local host is normally 127.0.0.1. All 127.x.x.x addresses are considered loopback addresses. I think Firefox is the exception in this case.

> "Loopback" IP addresses:
>
> ```
>     127.0.0.0 - 127.255.255.255
> ```
>
> Each computer on the Internet uses
>   127.0.0.0/8 to identify itself, to itself. 127.0.0.0 to 127.255.255.255
>   is earmarked for what is called
>   "loopback". This construct allows a
>   computer to establish/validate its IP
>   stack. Most software only uses
>   127.0.0.1 for loopback purposes (the other addresses in this range are
>   seldom used). All of the addresses
>   within the loopback address are
>   treated with the same levels of
>   restriction in Internet routing, so it
>   is difficult to use any other
>   addresses within this block for
>   anything other than node specific
>   applications, generally bootstraping.
>   This is documented in RFC 3330.

(taken from IANA.org)

The 0.0.0.0 address is:

> 0.0.0.0/8 reserved for self-identification [RFC5735]

(taken again from IANA)

and in details:

> 0.0.0.0/8 - Addresses in this block refer to source hosts on "this"
>      network.  Address 0.0.0.0/32 may be used as a source address for this
>      host on this network; other addresses within 0.0.0.0/8 may be used to
>      refer to specified hosts on this network ([RFC1122], Section
>      3.2.1.3).

(taken from RFC 5735)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost), the only correct address (reserved explicitly for that purpose) is `127.0.0.1`. I don't think it's correct to treat `0.0.0.0` as localhost - Firefox doesn't do it for me on Windows 7, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses#Reserved_IPv4_addresses) says that 0.0.0.0 is used for "broadcast messages to the current ("this") network as specified by [RFC 1700](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1700), page 4."

I would suggest that Opera is correct, as Firefox is interpreting an address that is only valid as a source address as a destination address.

Comment: Mmmm, I'm not a network expert, but the "current network" is *not* identical with the local host is it?